# C pointer arithmetic for 2D arrays

Tags: c, pointers

```
// strings is a 2D array (each string is 11 bytes long)
char strings[][11] = {"0123456789", "2222244444", "3333366666"};   

printf("String 3 Character 2 is %c\n", strings[2][1]);
```

How can I code this print statement using pointer arithmetic instead of the `strings[2][1]` ?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.  What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: The index operator is pointer arithmetic in disguise.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question; after all it's what SO is intended for, is it not? (if we ignore the possibility of it being homework).

Comment: needs more detail, seems like homework.

If you mean 'how can I iterate through these array elements' then please update the question.

Answer (score 13):

In C, `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)` (and since addition is commutative, that implies that it's also equivalent to `b[a]`. People writing for the International Obfuscated C Code Contest frequently rely on this, using things like `x["string"];`. Needless to say, it's best to avoid that sort of thing unless you're intentionally being evil though...

Edit:For anybody who's sure their understanding of the subject is up to snuff should feel free to analyze the following and correctly predict its output before running it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *c[] = { "ENTER", "NEW", "POINT", "FIRST" };
char **cp[] = { c+3, c+2, c+1, c };
char ***cpp = cp;

main()
{
    printf("%s", **++cpp);
    printf("%s ", *--*++cpp+3);
    printf("%s", *cpp[-2]+3);
    printf("%s\n", cpp[-1][-1]+1);
    return 0;
}
```

If memory serves, the credit (blame?) for that particular code goes to Thad Smith.

Answer (score 0):

How did I do with this?

```
char strings[][11] = { "0123456789", "2222244444", "3333366666" }; 
printf("String 3 Character 2 is %c\n", *(*(strings + 2) + 1));
```

Comment: Pretty poorly. It's `strings[2][1]` in the example. You're printing out a nonexistent `strings[3][1]`. Also, you don't need the `&` operator here - it's harmless, but totally superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *(*(strings+2)+1)
```