# Printing pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

It prints 3 while I want to print 2. I do not understand the reason when I am incrementing only once. Also let me know if this is correct use of pointers t pointers? I just made a sample code to see how pointers to pointers work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int a2[] = {7,8,9,10,11,12};
int *a3 = a1;
int *a4 = a2;
int **a[2];
a[0] = a3;
a[1] = a4;

printf("%d",*(++(*a)));



}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do the increment in the function argument.

Comment: Where is the function argument? I don't understand what you said. Please elaborate, I am new to C.

Comment: Short answer to your second question: No. More thorough answer: He|| no! This is utterly insane.

Comment: I'm not going to stop until it's valid code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540026/inconsistent-lvalue-required-error-when-incrementing-array-variable#comment25510107_17540026

Comment: @Bhaskar void main is not standard, you should use int main instead. Also, this code does not compile for me. However, if I change `int **a[2];` to `int *a[2]` I get the expected print of 2 (and not 3 as your question suggests.

Comment: It's compiling for gcc.

Comment: repeating same mistake again uff.

Comment: `a[0] = a3;` should produce compilation error

Comment: @Bhaskar, What version and options?

Comment: @Bhaskar https://ideone.com/u2W7k3, you are correct (I'm using visual studio) however it prints 2, not 3.

Comment: It's throwing warning but it compiles.

Comment: Also, this is not for [tag:C++]. It's more on [tag:C]. I don't see any significant C++ things here that warrants this question tag [tag:C++].

Comment: @Borgleader - For me it's showing 3. Dunno y

Comment: @Saksham - What dod i repeat? Please elaborate. This time I am not incrementing an array. ?

Comment: @Borgleader because `int **a[2]` will make things nastier.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain where I am wrong and what's the correct use of pointers to pointers?

Comment: I get warnings when compiling: warning C4047: '=' : 'int **' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'

Comment: There's *rarely* a good reason for a pointer to a pointer in C++. In C, it would typically be to implement a dynamic array of strings, or to modify a pointer (e.g., when adding the first item to a linked list). In case you want an even more demented challenge than this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1871265/179910

Comment: well question is valid..but he seems to be not showing his complete code..:)

Comment: @Bhaskar array of pointers will suffice things in many cases and for dereferencing  you may need to do like `**a;`

Comment: I am not building any application but just learning C. And so trying things.

Comment: I am using fedora 17, GCC 4.7.2

Comment: @chris: [Plan 9](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/programming/c_programming_in_plan_9) uses `void main` explicitly, but I doubt that this program is intended to run on Plan 9.

Comment: Do people really not realize that it's an issue of 64 vs. 32 bit? By incrementing by the size of a pointer rather than an int, it skips an extra int.

Comment: Consider and understand @chris comments to your questions.

Comment: @JimBalter - Yes I am using 64 bit Fedora. But how does it affect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared a as an array of `int**`, so `*a` is not a pointer to int but a pointer to pointer to int. Incrementing a pointer adds the size of the data type it points to, so `++*a` advances the value at at `a[0]` by the size of a pointer.

What you actually stored in `a[0]` is a pointer to int, not a pointer to pointer to int. This is wrong and the compiler should have warned you about this. On your architecture it seems that a pointer is double the size of an int, so the increment `++*a` adds the size of two ints to the pointer, so the value at a[0], if interpreted as `int*` instead of `int **`, skips over the 2.

To get the results you expect declare a as an array of `int *`.

```
int *a[2];
```

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one here who got this right. The "answers" and comments here are one of the worst cases of the blind leading the blind that I've seen at SO.

Comment: Does assigning a[0] ad a[1] to pointer to pointer to int solvs purpose? Is this correct?
a[0] = &a3;
a[1] = &a4;

Comment: @JimBalter - since you advocated that Joni is right then can you please explain on my above comment?

Comment: @Bhaskar `a[0]` will have pointer to pointer.so a[0]=&a3(where `a3` is pointer) is perfectly correct.

Comment: But it does not print the values right!

Comment: @Dayalrai `a[0]=&a3` is valid but then `++*a` is not ... that points `a[0]` past `a3`, and dereferencing the result is UB.

Comment: @Bhaskar Joni (and I, and others) told you what to do ... change `int **a[2]` to `int *a[2]` ... then your program will be correct.

Comment: @JimBalter - I got perfect answers using *a[2]
But I still want to make things work with **a[2]. For this I changed a[0] = &a3; a[1] = &a4; Now how do I print 2?

Comment: @Bhaskar See hyphasisgoat's answer. Beyond that, learn the language by reading tutorials on pointers, instead of just flailing around.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!
@JimBalter - I am refering this - http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/pointers.pdf

Can you suggest any better?

Comment: @Bhaskar That can help but it doesn't appear to address the issues here such as pointers to pointers, pointers to arrays of pointers, exactly what happens when you increment various sorts of pointers. I would read some of the other answers here about pointers to pointers, pointers and sizeof, etc., and google around for additional sources.

Comment: Ohkay! thanks :)
One quick question @JimBalter , a doubt. After changing a[0] = &a3; a[1] = &a4; Now to print 1 i have to use ***a
To me **a should have been used. Can you please explain?
This is my understanding - 
a has address of a3 so *a will take me to content of a3. Now **a should take me to content of address stored in a3 i.e. a1's 1st element. Where I am missing out?

Comment: Nevermind!. I got it. Silly of me to ask!

Comment: @Bhaskar See my comment on Korchkidu's answer. Specifically for your question, `*a` is equivalent to `a[0]` ... I assume that's what you figured out.

Comment: Yes @JimBalter I did figure out the same using some printf's but still don't understand that why *a is not a3.
I read in tutorial that array name is address to 1st element which is a3 so I thought *a should have been a3

Comment: @Bhaskar `*a` is `&a3` ... you said that explicitly: `a[0] = &a3`. Maybe it's time for sleep; I know it is here. `*a` is `&a3`, `**a` is `a3`, `***a` is `*a3` is `*a1` is 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33121/discussion-between-bhaskar-and-jim-balter)

Comment: @Bhaskar Nah, sorry, I've spent way too much time on this as is. Goodbye and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

- `*a` = `*(a + 0)` =  `a[0]` that contain address = `a3` , `int*`(in your code `a[0] = a3;`).
- `a3` points to first element of `a1` (in your code `int *a3 = a1;`, that is one) Hence `*a` point first element of of `a1`.
- By doing `++(*a)` you are pointing to next element in `a1` that is at index `1` and last by using `*` at `++(*a)` you are printing `1` indexed value in `a1` array that outputs:  `2`  thats is `a1[1]`

So, `*(++(*a))` actually `a1[1]`.

You code print `2` not `3`, check here your working code at [codepade](http://codepad.org/eUatlGN5)

Comment: But I don't know why my gcc is printing 3.

Comment: Are you sure the code you have in your question is the exact code you're compiling?

Comment: *a is not integer.It is pointer to integer so increment will be of pointer size not of integer size.Value '3' looks correct

Comment: @Dayalrai yes `*a` is not int but it points to `a3` that is `int*`. Am I wrong some where ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes it points to `a3` which is starting address of `a1`.Now increment is happening on this pointer so it will be +8 bytes(assuming size of pointer 8 Byte) means increament of two 4 bytes.

Comment: @Bhaskar check [**codepade**](http://codepad.org/eUatlGN5) and codepade is GCC compiler

Comment: @Bhaskar compile your code with -Wall option

Comment: I just checked. It is printing 2 indeed. But I am on fedore 17, gcc 4.7.2 which is stuck on 3

Comment: and about the two differnet outputs i guess it is undefined because of increment inside printf(); lack of sequence point between two executions.

Comment: @PHIfounder How do i use it?

Comment: @Dayalrai No its not undefined

Comment: @Bhaskar google it , its very simple :)

Comment: @Bhaskar `gcc -Wall -pedantic Codename.c -o outexename`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: main.cpp(8): warning C4047: '=' : 'int **' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'

Comment: @Bhaskar Tell me if you don't understand how it evaluates **`2`**

Comment: I do understand that it shoud evaluate to 2. Infact I expected that. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Dayalrai Yes it's UB but it has nothing to do with "increment inside printf" or sequence points ... that would only apply if the same lvalue were being evaluated more than once. See my answer for the correct explanation.

Comment: "Tell me if you don't understand how it evaluates 2" -- This is totally wrong. The behavior is undefined so it can print anything. For the actual reason that it prints 3 on the OP's system, see my answer.

Comment: @Bhaskar This answer is wrong and should not be accepted. The correct answers here are mine and Joni's.

Comment: @JimBalter No the answer I given is correct, no problem, increment of pointed is not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JimBalter and Grijesh i think we need to start a new thread to solve this confusion.I am going to post a new question.

Comment: @JimBalter, Dayalrai, I am not against to any one, I will remove my answer myself If i realize that answer is not correct. In my understanding answer is perfectly Correct.

Comment: Then you have not read Joni's answer, my answer, or a number of other comments here. The OP's code is wrong and has undefined behavior -- it gets warnings from gcc -Wall. It prints 2 on systems where ints and pointers are the same size, but not on systems where they are not. Your answer totally ignores the fact that `a` has the wrong type for the assignments to it.

Comment: @Dayalrai We don't have to start anything just because some inexperienced programmers are confused ... both Joni and I posted perfectly good, correct answers that exactly explain the OP's results.

Comment: " increment of pointed is not undefined behaviour" -- It is undefined behavior to assign an `int*` value (a3) to an `int**` (a[0]) and then autoincrement it.

Comment: @Dayalrai my this answer is correct for posted question. its not undefined answer but answer is 2

Answer (score 2):

```
a[0] = &a3;
a[1] = &a4;

printf("%d",*(++(**a)));
```

As per definition, a is supposed to contain pointer to int pointer. So need to add & in front of a3 and a4. In printf need to use de-reference twice before incrementing for same reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently using a compiler with 64-bit pointers and 32-bit ints. Because you have declared `a` incorrectly, when you increment `*a` you are incrementing by the size of a pointer -- 64 bits, which is 8 bytes -- rather than the size of an int -- 32 bits, which is 4 bytes -- so effectively you increment by the size of two ints.

Change the declaration of `a` to

```
int* a[2];
```

and your program will behave correctly. Also, compile with -Wall (at least) to get warnings.

Comment: I got you I didn't notice precisely that defalcation is  `int **a[2];`  then assignment to `a[0] =` is wrong : Sorry man

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Well, I'm glad you finally got it ... it's only been mentioned half a dozen times by various people. Anyway, apology accepted.

Comment: Can you see deleted answers **?**

Comment: But if I change assignment of a[0] = &a1 i.e. pointer to pointer to int then also it does not work but throwing random value.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, I can't see a deleted answer.

Comment: @Bhaskar Making that change is wrong and is not what I suggested. Compile with gcc -Wall and it will give you warnings; &a1 is not an `int**`.

Comment: OP is using int **a[2] explicitly.

Comment: @Korchkidu The OP is also setting `a[0] = a3` and `a[1] = a4` explicitly. The OP's usage is inconsistent and wrong, and the OP wants to print 2 but is printing 3; I explained why that is happening, and how to avoid it. There are other ways as well, but changing the definition of `a` is the simplest way and the way most consistent with the OP's code. To keep `int **a[2]` requires changes to at least 3 other lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the pointer itself and again printing it..

So,

```
printf("%d",*(++(*a)));//would print 2

printf("%d",*(++(*a)));//would print 3
```

---

You should use `*((*a)+1)`

Comment: Not sure it is sufficient. The initial source code produces warnings.

Comment: @Korchkidu well it depends on the compiler you are using..but its working [here](http://codepad.org/iHe68gFY)

Comment: Well, the one you are using does not even trigger a warning for something like func(){} in C.

Comment: @Bhaskar as i said you are incrementing the pointer somewhere..check your code..

Comment: Completely wrong. Please see Joni's answer or mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int a2[] = {7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int *a3 = a1;
    int *a4 = a2;
    int **a[2];
    a[0] = &a3; // a3 is a pointer, so take its address to get a pointer to pointer
    a[1] = &a4; // same here

    printf("%d",*(*(a[0])+1)); // PRINTS 2
    printf("%d",*(*(a[1])+1)); // PRINTS 8

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a[0] is &a3. *a[0] is a3. **a[0] is *a3 is 1. ++(**a[0]) will change a1[0] from 1 to 2, so this will print 2, but probably not the way the OP wants.

Comment: @JimBalter: thanks Jim. I am not even sure to understand what he asked actually^^

Comment: I believe he wants to print a1[1], not ++a1[0].

Comment: @JimBalter: then why using ++? Wouldn't be + 1 more clear here?