# Is printf("%d",*(++(*a))); Undefined

Tags: c

is `printf("%d",*(++(*a)));` Undefined? Here `a` is pointer to a pointer to integer.

I do not have anymore code other than this.It is an extension of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540945/printing-pointer-to-pointer) question which had created lots of confusions.Just want to know what is happening in this print.Does it depend on Architechture(32 Vs 64) or compiler versions.

Hoping answers will be descriptive and clear.

Comment: Please specify here the type of `a` and all other variables it points as I assume the linked question has compiler warnings.

Comment: hmmm,in that case I agree with Bart's answer..

Comment: This expression is well defined, in that question `3` answer can be possible if he defined `int* a[2]` that points to `int` where Bahsker defined the like `int **a[2]` that points to `int*`

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with the question that confused you other than to illustrate that you are confused and don't understand the issues there ... you've gotten the situation wrong and have omitted the important information. In that question, `a` was an *array* of `int**`, and the UB was specifically because an `int*` was assigned to `a[0]`, which is a type mismatch. (@VoidPointer was correct.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you break it down, it does this:

1. Take the **value** of what `a` is pointing at: `*a`
2. Increment by one `++(*a)`
3. Dereference that `*(++(*a))`

So, if the **value+1**  of what is stored at `a` is a valid pointer, this will work. Otherwise, the result is undefined and will most likely result in a runtime error.

Comment: The expression is well-defined. Whether or not it will cause runtime failure is irrelevant.

Comment: "Probably not"? We can't know without type information, but if `a` is of type, for example, `int**`, then this is perfectly valid.

Comment: @amalloy agreed. I missed the "pointer to a pointer to integer" remark of the poster.

Comment: Hah, I missed it too. I was just giving him the benefit of the doubt :).

Comment: This answer is unfortunately not very useful because you didn't read the link and realize that the OP quite misdescribed and underdescribed the situation there.

Comment: @icepack Whether it is well-defined depends on the value of `a` ... for instance, if `a` is uninitialized, this is obviously undefined behavior. The same goes for various other values of `a` for which the standard does not specify the behavior ... as is the case with the original question. This has everything to do with whether there will be a runtime error ... conforming programs will not get errors for this statement unless printf fails for some reason related to I/O or memory allocation.

Comment: @amalloy *if a is of type, for example, `int**`* -- but it isn't; the OP got it wrong. `a` is defined as `int **a[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code is correct and even if cryptic can make some (little) sense as in:

```
void print_next(int **a) {
   printf("%d\n",*(++(*a)));
}


int arr[] = {1,5,6,3,5,6};
int *p = arr;

while (p<arr+6) 
   print_next(&p);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your question is specifically about `*(++(*a))` expression, then there's nothing undefined here (assuming all pointers involved are valid). There are no attempts to perform multiple modifications of the same object. There are no independent reads of any of the modified objects. End of story.

Basically, there's nothing to explain here, since the code is perfectly fine in a rather straightforward manner. There's really no room for anything more "descriptive and clear" than that.

If this is not sufficiently clear, you have to explain what exactly looks suspicious to you in this expression.

Comment: + please make italic/ or bold *`nothing undefined`*

Comment: Andrey, you need to read the question that the OP cited. The OP's description is quite wrong and omits important details ... particularly that `*a*` is of type `int**` but had an `int*` assigned to it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You should know by now that the critical text is *assuming all pointers involved are valid*. Since `*a` is of type `int**` but an `int*` was assigned to it, the assumption is false.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I can't really establish a meaningful connection between `a` in this question and `a` in the linked question. In the linked question `a` is an `int **[2]`. Here the OP states that `a` is an `int **`. These two situations are semantically different and incompatible. For this reason I have to go with the description given in this question - `a` is an `int **` - and ignore the initializations made in the linked one.

Comment: As I've pointed out in comments here, the OP is grossly confused, mischaracterized the cited question, and omitted all the important information ... a very good reason to vote to close the question.